# Помогите разобратся в vk_api.audio.VkAudio(python)

Tags: vkontakte-api

Есть данная строка:

audio.VkAudio.get_audio_by_id(self, owner_id, audio_id)
и owner и audio id у меня Есть

Но что должно прийти на self. если без него, то пишет ошибку
get_audio_by_id() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

если просто self 
то он не определенный(нужно ему что передать)
А что ж передать то?

Answer (score 0):

С данной библиотекой не работал но работал с закрытым api vk. Для получения данных о музыке, названия, логотипа и тд. требуются данные авторизации. self в питоне это аналог this в других языках. Следовательно вам надо передать сам объект `подключения` этой библиотеки

вот [документация](https://vk-api.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: Спасибо. Пробовал с 2. С 2 не катит. Требует self. я делал через токен группы. Попробую авториз

Comment: Попробуйте другой вариант, я описал его в ответе.